# Po Shen Loh's Method

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

I'm a junior in High School, and I came across Po Shen Loh's method for roots and I was wondering if this would also work for Equations with a degree of 4 or if it only applies for Quadratics, again I am Junior in High School so I am just starting to do my research in Mathematics!.

I have this question since I have seen some people define a variable for a polynomial to the 4th degree like `let A = x^2` and then they treat is a quadratic.

Comment: Po Shen Loh's method relies on that $\frac{-b}{2a}$ is the midpoint of the roots. This follows from Vieta's formulas.

Comment: It's just a slightly different way to obtain the roots of a quadratic.  It has nothing to do with equations of higher degree.

Comment: For higher degree polynomials, you can use Newton's identities (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) and Vieta's formulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: This method has been known for ages, and it certainly isn't Po Shen Loh's. It is how the quadratic formula is taught in Germany, as well as being used in one of [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e50Bj7jn9IQ)'s videos.